# Configuring Gmail in gnus in Aquamacs

Tags: emacs, aquamacs, gnus

I'm a new emacs user, and I'm trying to get gnus working with mi gmail account with Aquamacs.

So far, I've been able to set it up to receive my mail. The problem is when I try to send an e-mail. I get this error:

```
No Gnus is good news
No more unread newsgroups
Mark set
Sending...
Sending via mail...
No STARTTLS program was available (tried 'gnutls-cli')
ad-Orig-error: Sending failed; SMTP protocol error
```

I understand that 'gnutls-cli' is necessary, and that it is not included in Aquamacs. I've found this guide to install it http://www.gnu.org/s/gnutls/manual/gnutls.html, but I'm not sure how I have to proceed, since I'm using MacOs and not Linux (although both are UNIX OS)

My question is: what do I exactly have to do to be able to send emails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could install opensll and configure Gnus to use it instead of
gnus-tls.

From the Gnus Manual:

> `nntp-open-ssl-stream'
>        Opens a connection to a server over a "secure" channel.  To use
>        this you must have OpenSSL (http://www.openssl.org) or SSLeay
>        (ftp://ftp.psy.uq.oz.au/pub/Crypto/SSL) installed.  You then
>        define a server as follows:
>
> ```
>       ;; "snews" is port 563 and is predefined in our `/etc/services'
>       ;; however, `openssl s_client -port' doesn't like named ports.
>       ;;
>       (nntp "snews.bar.com"
>             (nntp-open-connection-function nntp-open-ssl-stream)
>             (nntp-port-number 563)
>             (nntp-address "snews.bar.com"))
> ```

Comment: Firs of all, thank you for your answer.
Finally, I figured out how to install gnutls. I have macports installed, so I simply tried
    `sudo ports install gnutls` And it worked!

Anyway, as I've said, thank you for taking your time to answer.

Comment: Do you mean `sudo port install gnutls`?